# Cast a column to binary datatype in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binary

I have a Spark use case where I have to create a null column and cast to a binary datatype. I tried the below but it is not working. When I replace Binary by integer, it works. I also tried BinaryType and Array[Byte]. Must be missing something here.

```
val ip1 = sqlContext.read
    .parquet("/home/hadoop/work/aa/bbb/ccc/data/today")
    .toDF();
val ip2 = ip1
    .withColumn("user_hll",lit("0"))
    .select(col("start_timestamp_hr"),col("user_hll"))
    .withColumn("hll",col("user_hll").cast("Binary"))
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a null binary column, all you need is:

`.withColumn("hll", lit(null).cast(org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType))`

Answer (score 1):

instead of casting you could also use `lit` directly

```
.withColumn("hll",lit("0".getBytes)) // gives [30]
```

or

```
.withColumn("hll",lit(Array.empty[Bytes])) // gives []
```

or if you want `ǹull`, you can do :

```
.withColumn("hll",typedLit(Option.empty[Array[Byte]])) // gives null
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Simple miss from my side

```
.cast("Binary")
```

Any better way would be appreciated